# snmpd doesn't respond when I compile from source

Tags: installation, snmp, net-snmp

OS that I am using: Fedora 15.

Today morning, I removed net-snmp rpm package previously installed on my system. Then,  I compiled and installed snmp from source. Compiled snmpd does not respond to any get requests.

I installed the package by executing these commands:

```
./.configure && make && make install
```

After a while it was done and I find the installation was successful.

For testing the installation I ran a `get` request:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 sysDescr.0
```

Weird I feel, no response...
What could I be missing? a super-user privilege is required?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Additionally, there are few steps that need to be performed for installation from source.

Follow here,

Step 1: Log in as root (su - root)

Step 2: Navigate to the home folder where the net-snmp tar.gz is kept
Issue this command at the prompt

```
tar -zxvf net-snmp-5.5.tar.gz
```

(I still happen to use v 5.5. Change this with your version)

Step 3: Navigate to the un-tarred directory.

Step 4: `Run ./configure`

Step 5: `make`

Step 6: `make install`

Step 7: You now have netsnmp installed and ready to use.

Ha Ha .. not quite.. there are still lot of stuff that needs to be done before we can say...yep..thats working beautifully..

Step 8: Navigate to `/usr/local/bin` to see if the folder has a bunch of snmp stuff like *snmpconf snmptranslate* and so on...

Step 9: Also see if the `/usr/local/share/snmp/mibs` folder and see if all the MIB files are present..

Step 10: If everything is fine until here try to do some configurations checking (else start-over).
Run,

```
net-snmp-config --default-mibdirs
```

and you must get the output

```
/root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/local/share/snmp/mibs
```

Run,

```
net-snmp-config --snmpconfpath
```

output should be like

```
/usr/local/etc/snmp:/usr/local/share/snmp:/usr/local/lib/snmp:/root/.snmp:/var/net-snmp
```

Step 11: Run,

```
ldd /usr/local/bin/snmptranslate
```

output will be:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00110000)
       libnetsnmpagent.so.15 => not found
       libnetsnmphelpers.so.15 => not found
       libnetsnmpmibs.so.15 => not found
       libnetsnmp.so.15 => not found
```

This means that you might get snmp*: error while loading shared libraries:
like for example as mentioned above libnetsnmp.so.20: It cannot open shared object file.

**If no error comes like above , no need to do anything, but if error comes, then, you have to do the steps below**
Edit ld.so.conf in /etc and add the details of the lib path of /usr/local/lib and then run ldconfig

```
vi /etc/ld.so.conf

/usr/X11R6/lib/Xaw3d
/usr/X11R6/lib
/usr/lib/Xaw3d
/usr/i386-suse-linux/lib
/usr/local/lib
/opt/kde3/lib
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

(I happen to Use Suse a lot. But something is also very similar to Debian)

Step 12: Run,

```
ldconfig
```

Step 13: Now you have to tell netsnmp where to look for MIB files. You use the snmpconf command to do this. Issue this command at the prompt.

```
snmpconf
```

This is what it will appear on your screen,

*I can create the following types of configuration files for you.
Select the file type you wish to create:
(you can create more than one as you run this program)
  1:  snmpd.conf
  2:  snmptrapd.conf
  3:  snmp.conf
Other options: quit*

Select File: 3

*The configuration information which can be put into snmp.conf is divided
into sections.  Select a configuration section for snmp.conf
that you wish to create:
  1:  Debugging output options
  2:  Textual mib parsing
  3:  Output style options
  4:  Default Authentication Options
Other options: finished*

Select section: finished

*I can create the following types of configuration files for you.
Select the file type you wish to create:
(you can create more than one as you run this program)
  1:  snmpd.conf
  2:  snmptrapd.conf
  3:  snmp.conf
Other options: quit*

Select File: quit

*The following files were created:
 snmp.conf*

*These files should be moved to /usr/local/share/snmp if you
want them used by everyone on the system.  In the future, if you add
the -i option to the command line I'll copy them there automatically for you.*

*Or, if you want them for your personal use only, copy them to
/root/.snmp .  In the future, if you add the -p option to the
command line I'll copy them there automatically for you.*

Step 14: Copy the snmp.conf file.

```
cp snmp.conf /usr/local/share/snmp/
```

Step 15: Finally try this.

```
snmptranslate -Tp -IR ipMIB
```

You will observe a tree structure on your screen.
This means that everything that you have installed is working

So now the errors are not going to be there because of configuration.. 
whatever gets screwed up , its your responsibilty ;-)

Cheers,